How to mock a node module import in node js
I am using mocha as my testing environment in my node project and Sinon to stub and mock dependencies.
I have a File Factory.js as
import fs from 'fs'

class Factory{
   create = async(options) => {
    if(fs.existsSync(options.wokerPath)){
     const {Worker} = await import(options.wokerPath);
     const worker = new Worker(options);
     const result = await worker.process();
   }
  }
}

Worker.js File as
import { RepoWorker } from "../RepoWorker.js";
import excelToJson from "convert-excel-to-json";



class Worker extends RepoWorker {

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }


    process = async () => {
        try{
            const result = excelToJson({
                sourceFile: this.inputPath,
                header: {
                    rows: 1
                },
                columnToKey: {
                    '*': '{{columnHeader}}'
                }
            });
    
            return result;
        }
        catch(ex){
            this.logger.console.error("Error inside Generic ExcelParser",ex);
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
}

export { Worker }


I have mocked fs and existsSync method Like :
Sinon.stub(fs, 'existsSync').callsFake((inputPath) => {
            if(inputPath == 'TestPath'){
            return true;
            }
        })

I am able to return true by mocking fs and existsSync Like this.
How can I mock excelToJson to return some mock data without giving it path to an actual file in my test Cases.
I tried
import * as ExcelToJsonMocule from 'convert-excel-to-json';

sinon.stub(ExcelToJsonModule, 'default').callsFake((options) => {
        if (options.sourceFile === 'TestPath') {
            return {
                Sheet1: [
                    { column1: 'value1', column2: 'value2' },
                    { column1: 'value3', column2: 'value4' }
                ]
            };
        }
    });

And got error
Getting Type Error Es Modules Cannot be stubbed

You can't do this with mocha and sinon alone. That you could do this for fs is a lucky incident because it's legacy module that has default import for cjs/esm interop. Module mocking is a separate functionality. This alone is enough to switch to Jest that has it out of the box. It's unknown how you use esm. If you transpile to cjs, you can use proxyquire, etc. For native esm you can try esmock, I didn't test it with mocha
